# warnings hidden by gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have written a R function which runs the `lmer()` function from the `lme4` package. Sometimes the `lmer()` function returns some warnings, then I see these warnings when running my function.

However when running my function through an R `gWidget` the warnings do not appear in the R console. They appear only after I run a new command in the R console. What should I do to see these warnings when running the widget?

I don't know whether my question is clear. My function is very long, a little complex, and takes a file as an argument. I can't copy it here and provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons I think gWidgets redirect the output.
One solution is to change the `options` `warn`

I create a small code to generate the bug. and I confirm I have the same behaviour.

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

warn.handler <- function(h,...) { warnings('dummy warning')}
win    <- gwindow("Hello World, ad nauseum", visible=TRUE)
 group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win)
 obj   <- gbutton("Hello...",container=group,handler = warn.handler)
```

here my warn.handler function generate a dummy warning :

```
warn.handler()
Warning message:
In warn.handler() : dummy warning
```

but when I run the gwidget , and I click on the button  I don't have the warnings.

when I change the options warn

```
        options(warn=1) # print warnings as they occur
```

I get the warnings.